# Tengo problemas con urllib2 en Python 2.71

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Tengo esta peticición:

```
import urllib2     
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
print f.read(100)
```

pero cuando la ejecuto en Python 2.7.1, me apareceel siguiente error:

> AttributeError:'modulo' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: En principio el código es correcto para Python 2.x, no para python 3.x pero ese no es tu caso según dices, por lo que debería correr sin problemas.¿Tu módulo no se llamará por casualidad `urllib2.py`? Estaría bien que pusieras el error que te retorna al completo. Prueba en la consola interactiva del IDLE o en la terminal del SO llamando al intérprete a ejecutar esas lineas a ver si te lanza también el error o no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te falta el Request:

```
import urllib2
r = urllib2.Request('https://www.python.org/')
u = urllib2.urlopen(r)
response = u.read()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: La respuesta es tecnicamente correcta. La he probado y me lo he leido. Que es lo que te llevo a votar negativamente la respuesta? Y como lo mejorarias. Por que de verdad, no lo entindo

Comment: Zartch, Yo no he votado negativamente a tu respuesta, solo edité el texto.

Comment: Creo que a lo que se refiere @Mauricio es: Que siempre es bueno explicar el porque del codigo que propones, para muchos la solucion que colocaste es entendible y ovia, pero para las personas nuevas quizas no tanto. E inclusos algunos no llegan a ver la diferencia entre el inconveniente y la solucion.

Comment: Hola @OrlandoDeLaRosa Tu explicación es Lógica. Aplicable a ambos casos. A mi respuesta y al comentario de "Leete las reglas". Con la diferencia de que mi respuesta es simple, concisa y exactamente lo que se ha preguntado. Y el comentario es vago y general sin apuntar nada ni resolver nada.
Pero si tienes razón a la respuesta le falta una pequeña explicación.